# phpCAS and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cas

I'm looking for some guidance on how to integrate phpCAS with CodeIgniter.

I've been searching for 2 days and have gotten nowhere.

Does anyone have solid examples of how to do this? I've use authorization libraries for CI in the past but my newest project requires CAS integration.

Thanks for any help you can send my way.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried much. I've downloaded the phpCAS libary, put it in application/libraries, and created a library that includes CAS.php. I have no idea where to go from there or if I'm even heading in the right direction.

Comment: Well, I was thinking this morning about maybe writing a wrapper that calls the proper phpCAS methods but I really don't know where to start. ANY help would be great. I would love to 'try' but I dont know where to start.

Comment: Maybe as a start, could you show how you are loading and calling it?

Comment: Do you already have a CAS server, and only need to do the client?

Answer (score 0):

I've started a library for CAS authentication for CodeIgniter, and posted the code and some explanation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11802811/149872).

See also the documentation on phpCAS: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS+examples